# Noetherian objects are stable by extension

Tags: abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. An object $M$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is noetherian if any ascending chain of subobjects of $M$ is stationary. (In analogy with modules.)

I am trying to prove that if $$0\rightarrow M' \stackrel{f}\rightarrow M\stackrel{g}\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$$
is a short exact sequence in $\mathcal{A}$, the object $M$ is noetherian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ are noetherian. (I am looking for an argument that is not using the Freyd–Mitchell theorem.)

I was able to prove that if $M'$ and $M''$ are noetherian, then $M$ is noetherian. I am stuck proving the other implication, in particular that the preimage of a subobject under an epimorphism is an epimorphism to the subobject.